# Struts2 result type not calling portlet

Tags: java, struts2, portlet

Now This is something strange !!

/viewClientFXPortlet
   /createFXReports.jsp

when my action class returns the result "reportsuccessful" it doesnot call the /viewClientFXPortlet rather that it keeps on calling the same portlet infinite times due to which jvm crashes . if i replace the portlet with a jsp page it works fine . what is need is to call the portlet. Any help will b greatly appreciated .

Comment: What do you mean by calling portlet? Are you trying to pass parameters from one portlet to another?

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed trying to pass parameters between portlets you will nide something called Inter Portlet Communication (IPC)